# How to iterate through BaseObject property of PSObject in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, system.management

I have a list of PSObject items that are returned on calling the `.Invoke()` method while using the `System.Management.Automation` package. On debugging this, I can see the values of the objects that I want to print in the `BaseObject` and `ImmediateBaseObject` properties. However, on using the `foreach` loop to iterate through the results, and printing the `BaseObjects` of each item just prints the type of the item (`System.Collections.ArrayList`). How do I store the value of BaseObjects into a variable?

Here is the code and some screenshots:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var results = ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@".\PSScripts\test_func2.ps1")).Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject result in results)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
             outList.Add(result.BaseObject.ToString())
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `results` object during debugging, which only has arrays of relevant data. Hidden due to privacy reasons.
[image: This is the result object, which only has arrays of relevant data]

This is the `result` object > BaseObject view during debugging. The `result` object's members property does not have the relevant data.
[image: results object]

And this is the output I get on executing the above code:

[image: output on execution gives System.Collections.Arraylist as output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking to receive back custom objects rather than ArrayLists you need to look at your ps1 script and modify it to return objects

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I resolved the issue, but this seems like the better way to do it. Thing is, I already am returning an object array of basetype System.Array from the script. What could I change?

Comment: I'd have to see your ps1 script to see how you are outputting a collection of arraylists instead of objects.  You can post a new question with that code asking how you could change the output from arraylists to objects to get further help with that.  Either way, happy for you that you found a solution for your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating an `IList` object and casting my `result` object to `IList`. I can then iterate through the values of the IList variable. Here, `res` is a `List<String[]>` object declared with function level scope that can hold all values of the `results` object.

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
IList collection = (IList)result.BaseObject;
foreach(var x in collection)
{
    temp.Add((string)x);
}
res.Add(temp.ToArray());
```

Comment: It looks to me that the only problem with your original code is that you called `.ToString()` on `result.BaseObject`, which predictably gives you the output you saw; try `([System.Collections.ArrayList] @()).ToString()` from a PowerShell window, for instance.